# Did slang "hang" meaning "turn" as in "hang a left" relate at all to boxing slang?

Tags: etymology, slang

[*Green's Dictionary of Slang*](https://greensdictofslang.com/search/basic?q=hang) gives this definition of "hang," referring to **turning left or right in a car**, with a citation from 1966.

> (orig. US) to turn a corner in a motorcar; as in *hang a left*, *hang a right*.

There are many earlier uses of the phrase "hang a left" and "hang a right," but they appear to mostly refer to throwing a punch with the left or right arm respectively, especially in boxing, but sometimes applying outside of sport.

In these cases, it is often described as a left or right "hook," or "jab," as in **hang a left hook** or **hang a left jab**.

I haven't found this sense defined in either the *OED* or in *GDoS*, but citations are not hard to find.

> Berg **hangs** a left jab on Tony's ear in the seventh

[image]

-[**1931** - *Daily News* (New York, NY) 11 Sep](https://www.newspapers.com/image/414663371/?terms=%22hang%2Ba%2Bleft%22) (paywall)

Sometimes, this sense is also used without a following object like "hook" or "jab," as with "hanging a left" in your car, a boxer can "hang a left" on their opponent and the meaning is clear.

> Richard Li Brandi... **hangs a left** on jaw of Lawrence Greene

[image]

- [**1934** - *Daily News* (New York, NY) 20 Mar](https://www.newspapers.com/image/415739049/?terms=%22hang%2Ba%2Bleft%22) (paywall)

Based on my research, it appears that ***throw* a left hook** is the most common term in boxing for referring to a punch, with **hang** perhaps being more colloquial.

**Question**:

- What sense of the word "hang" is being used in boxing when it refers to a punch?  Is it slang that developed exclusively in boxing, or does this notion of "hanging" meaning throwing a punch go back further, or exist in other domains?
- Did this "hang a [direction]" pattern have any influence on the more recent slang for turning right or left in a car, or are the two senses of the word "hang" in any way related?

Comment: Re driving, I had always assumed that the "hang" as in reference to figuratively reaching out and grabbing a tree or some such, to force a "swing" in the intended direction.  One might literally do this when, eg, running through a forest.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53993/etymology-of-the-expression-make-a-larry-i-e-turn-left

Comment: Ngram finds [this from 1907](https://books.google.com/books?id=lFICAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA186&dq=%22hung+a+left%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjt0-rGmu3lAhVNrZ4KHSKIBUkQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22hung%20a%20left%22&f=false) for "hung a left" in the boxing sense.

Comment: There apparently was a song "Hung a Left" by Domenic Mercurio in 1968.

Comment: [This bit by William Safire](https://books.google.com/books?id=dOT8okA-dCQC&q=%22hang+a+left%22&dq=%22hang+a+left%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinu8OtnO3lAhWlGDQIHXppC9UQ6AEwBHoECAYQAg) suggests that "hang a left" refers to a skier making a turn:  *"Hang a draw," or "Hang a forty-four," which meant "One large root beer, please," has reappeared in the surfers' "hang ten" (to grip the edge of a surfboard with all ten toes) and the skiers' "hang a left" (to make a left turn). Soda-fountain ...*

Answer (score 3):

So far, the turning *hang* has plausible explanations without resorting to boxing jargon, though so far this is a partial answer.

Here is the directional use for **hang, v.**, as reported in the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com/view/Entry/83964), and first attested in 1967:

> colloquial (originally and chiefly U.S.). to hang a left, to hang a right, etc. (also jocular with proper names having the appropriate initial letter, as Louie, Ralph, etc.): to go or turn in the specified direction, esp. while travelling in a motor vehicle or on skis. Cf. sense 11d   below.
>
> 1967   Evening Standard 26 July 13/3   If you're in your pig [sc. car, in Detroit] and you ‘**hang** a Louie’, you've just turned left. If you ‘**hang** a Ralph’, it's a right turn, ‘**hang** a Sam’ is go straight and ‘**hang** a Ulysses’ means make a U-turn.
>
> 1975   L. Dills CB Slanguage Dict. 39   **Hang** a right (left), turn right or left.

Sense 11d refers to a horse veering to one side:

> d. Of a horse: to veer towards one side.
>
> 1951   E. Rickman Come Racing with Me ii. 16   Sarda II ‘**hanging**’ towards Native Heath..who won by a short head.

And this, in turn, is grouped with *hang* as leaning or hanging to one side (forward, backward, or to the side):

> a. To have the top bending or projecting beyond the lower part; to bend forward or downward; to lean over; (also) to incline steeply (see hanging adj. 2).
>
> OE   Beowulf 1363   Se mere..ofer þæm **hongiað** hrinde bearwas.
>
> [over it **hangs**      frost-covered groves, [source for translation](https://www.heorot.dk/beowulf-rede-text.html)]

So, one explanation would be that *hang a left* or *hang a right* would relate to the leaning action a horserider, skier, or other mover might do as they turn. This seems plausible. For a vehicle with an axle, it's as dead a metaphor as *turning on* a smartphone.

---

Meanwhile, the meaning of a punch may come from this meaning (under "to hang on"):

> 6. to hang one on: to deal (someone) a blow.
>
> 1908   K. McGaffey Sorrows of Show Girl 200   Hauling off wifey hangs one on Alla's map.
>
> 1960   B. Crump Good Keen Man 44   I'd thought for a moment he was going to hang one on me. The idea..had got his goat all right.

Note, however, that the OED is limited on this point, and does not reflect the usages like *hang a left jab* you found. So my next steps will be to try to find a connection between *hang* as a blow and *hang* as a turn that isn't reflected in the OED.

Comment: I'm sure I commonly heard "hang a right" some years prior to 1967.

Comment: I hadn't been familiar with the "to hang one on" phrase.  That's an interesting finding.

Comment: @HotLicks - this is from 1965 but there must be earlier usages.  “*But the pickup is all right and we cruise down Oak and then hang a right onto Chestnut and then Miss Priscilla's house comes up all ashy in front of us.“* https://books.google.it/books?id=9NBBAQAAIAAJ&q=%22hang+a+right%22&dq=%22hang+a+right%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRztm4i-3lAhUDGewKHW7ZCcQQ6AEIJzAA

Comment: @HotLicks I'm sure you're right. My plan once my son goes to bed is to find prior uses of *hang a right*.

Comment: A surfer will "hang ten" by stepping to the front of the board and curl 10 toes over the front edge of the board.